# Extract and Display information using webview and WxPython

Tags: html, python-2.7

I am creating a application where the UI is been formed using WxPython. I am using a Panel with a HTML window.

In this HTML page which is displayed, I would like to extract information, for example the text of a textBox, which radio button is selected, a click of a button etc, and at the same time show some information to the user, like when a process was been completed and its result or similar information.

I am not finding a good way of doing that, as long I could understand, I will need to use Javascript or something to interact with the page in some way. But I could not find how to send and receive information to the page, and if the wx.html.HtmlWindow supports Javascript.

What would be the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

<s>You could communicate through a socket. Create a local socket server on the python side, and then use javascript to connect to that socket. There are plenty examples of this around the web. See the docs for python Socket Server: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html</s>

It doesn't look like the [wx.html module](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.html.1moduleindex.html) supports javascript or css:

> This module contains a widget class and supporting classes for a generic HTML renderer. It supports only a subset of the HTML standards, and no Javascript or CSS, but it is relatively lightweight and has no platform dependencies. It is suitable for displaying simple HTML documents, such as the application’s documentation or built-in help pages.

It does look like you can handle the `EVT_HTML_LINK_CLICKED` event to tell when a user clicks a link, but I'm not sure how you would get the input from html form elements like textboxes, radio buttons, etc.

Your best bet may be to create a web app using a microframework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and serve the app locally.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. In this case, I could use Chrome to render my page, right? There will be no necessity of using a WebView from Wx.

Comment: @user2977500 That depends on what else you need your app to do. Are you adding functionality to an existing WxPython app? If you are simply planning on using the WxPython app as a container to display an html page, and need the functionality of html form elements, I would say that using a microframework like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) might be the easiest option. It also appears that the wx.html module does not support javascript or css. See my updated answer.